# Spring3.0 Autowired null

Tags: spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I am doing with Spring @MVC3 and I've got a problem. Spring beans are created, but @Autowired doesn't work in a class. Here is my setting and source code:

xxx-servlet-.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd"> 

   <context:annotation-config />     

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.lodestone.ccah.controller"/>  

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"/>     

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter" />
            </list>

        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

beans.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd 
    http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws 
    http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location" value="classpath:website.properties" />

    </bean>

    <bean id="contextApplicationContextProvider" class="com.lodestone.ccah.util.ApplicationContextProvider"></bean>

    <bean id="staticVars" class="com.lodestone.ccah.util.StaticVars">
        <property name="awsServerIp" value="${website.AWSServerIP}" />
        <property name="timeOutConnection" value="${website.timeOutConnection}" />
        <property name="timeOutReceive" value="${website.timeOutReceive}" />

    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" 
          class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" 
          destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="${db.url}?useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true" />
        <property name="username" value="${db.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
        <property name="maxIdle" value="10" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="100" />
        <property name="maxWait" value="10000" />
        <property name="validationQuery" value="select 1" />
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="false" />
        <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true" />
        <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="1200000" />
        <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="1800000" />
        <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="5" />
        <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <!-- DAO settings -->
    <bean id="mediaDao" class="com.lodestone.ccah.dao.MediaDao">
        <!--<property name="dataSource"     ref="dataSource"></property>-->
    </bean>

    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource"     ref="dataSource"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="mediaService" class="com.lodestone.ccah.service.MediaService"></bean>
 </beans>
```

Tomcat Log:

```
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Thu Mar 08 13:21:49 EST 2012]; root of context hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [beans.xml]
DEBUG: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader - Using JAXP provider [org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl]
DEBUG: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.PluggableSchemaResolver - Loading schema mappings from [META-INF/spring.schemas]
DEBUG: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.PluggableSchemaResolver - Loaded schema mappings: {http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-2.5.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/jms/config/spring-jms-2.5.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-3.0.xsd, http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/http-conf.xsd=schemas/configuration/http-conf.xsd, http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd=schemas/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.3.xsd=org/springframework/security/config/spring-security-3.0.3.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-2.0.1.xsd=org/springframework/security/config/spring-security-2.0.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-3.0.xsd, http://www.w3.org/2006/07/ws-policy.xsd=schemas/ws-policy-200607.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/oxm/config/spring-oxm-3.0.xsd, http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd=schemas/jaxrs.xsd, http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/wsrm-manager.xsd=schemas/configuration/wsrm-manager.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.0.xsd, http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing=schemas/wsdl/addressing.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/security/config/spring-security-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.0.xsd, http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd=schemas/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-2.5.xsd, http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/=schemas/wsdl/wsdl.xsd, http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/bindings/object.xsd=schemas/bindings/object.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd=org/springframework/web/servlet/config/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/flex/spring-flex-1.0.xsd=org/springframework/flex/config/xml/spring-flex-1.0.xsd, http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/jms.xsd=schemas/configuration/jms.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/jdbc/config/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd=org/springframework/jdbc/config/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd, http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/http-jetty.xsd=schemas/configuration/http-jetty.xsd, http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/=schemas/wsdl/http.xsd, http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/wsdl/jms.xsd=schemas/wsdl/jms.xsd, http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd=schemas/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-3.0.xsd, http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/rm/wsrm-policy.xsd=schemas/configuration/wsrm-policy.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/web/servlet/config/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-2.0.4.xsd=org/springframework/security/config/spring-security-2.0.4.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-3.0.xsd, http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/2003-02-11.xsd=schemas/wsdl/wsdl.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-2.5.xsd, http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/ws/addressing.xsd=schemas/ws-addr-conf.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.0.xsd, http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/wsdl/http-conf.xsd=schemas/wsdl/http-conf.xsd, http://www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd=schemas/xml.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-2.5.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms.xsd=org/springframework/jms/config/spring-jms-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm.xsd=org/springframework/oxm/config/spring-oxm-3.0.xsd, http://www.w3.org/2007/02/ws-policy.xsd=schemas/ws-policy-200702.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-2.5.xsd, http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/policy.xsd=schemas/policy.xsd, http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy/ws-policy.xsd=schemas/ws-policy-200409.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-2.5.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-2.5.xsd, http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/cxf-beans.xsd=schemas/configuration/cxf-beans.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task-3.0.xsd, http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd=schemas/core.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/jms/config/spring-jms-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-2.0.xsd, http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/security.xsd=schemas/configuration/security.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.4.xsd=org/springframework/security/config/spring-security-3.0.4.xsd, http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/soap.xsd=schemas/configuration/soap.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-2.0.2.xsd=org/springframework/security/config/spring-security-2.0.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-2.5.xsd, http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd=schemas/jaxws.xsd, http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/simple.xsd=schemas/simple.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd=org/springframework/security/config/spring-security-3.0.4.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/security/config/spring-security-3.0.xsd, http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr-2.0.xsd=org/directwebremoting/spring/spring-dwr-2.0.xsd, http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/wsrm-manager-types.xsd=schemas/configuration/wsrm-manager-types.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-3.0.xsd}
DEBUG: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.PluggableSchemaResolver - Found XML schema [http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd] in classpath: org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
DEBUG: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader - Loading bean definitions
DEBUG: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loaded 7 bean definitions from location pattern [classpath:beans.xml]
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Bean factory for Root WebApplicationContext: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@70d9cc1a: defining beans [propertyConfigurer,contextApplicationContextProvider,staticVars,dataSource,mediaDao,jdbcTemplate,mediaService]; root of factory hierarchy
DEBUG: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'propertyConfigurer'
DEBUG: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'propertyConfigurer'
DEBUG: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'propertyConfigurer' to allow for resolving potential circular references
DEBUG: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'propertyConfigurer'
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer - Loading properties file from class path resource [website.properties]
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Unable to locate MessageSource with name 'messageSource': using default [org.springframework.context.support.DelegatingMessageSource@b56efe]
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Unable to locate ApplicationEventMulticaster with name 'applicationEventMulticaster': using default [org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster@789e60f]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@70d9cc1a: defining beans [propertyConfigurer,contextApplicationContextProvider,staticVars,dataSource,mediaDao,jdbcTemplate,mediaService]; root of factory hierarchy
DEBUG: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'propertyConfigurer'
DEBUG: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'contextApplicationContextProvider'
DEBUG: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'contextApplicationContextProvider'
DEBUG: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'contextApplicationContextProvider' to allow for resolving potential circular references
DEBUG: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'contextApplicationContextProvider'
DEBUG: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'staticVars'
DEBUG: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'staticVars'
DEBUG: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'staticVars' to allow for resolving potential circular references
DEBUG: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'staticVars'
DEBUG: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'dataSource'
DEBUG: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'dataSource'
DEBUG: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'dataSource' to allow for resolving potential circular references
DEBUG: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'dataSource'
**DEBUG: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'mediaDao'**
DEBUG: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'mediaDao'
DEBUG: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'mediaDao' to allow for resolving potential circular references
DEBUG: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'mediaDao'
DEBUG: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'jdbcTemplate'
DEBUG: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'jdbcTemplate'
DEBUG: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'jdbcTemplate' to allow for resolving potential circular references
DEBUG: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'dataSource'
DEBUG: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'jdbcTemplate'
DEBUG: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'jdbcTemplate'
DEBUG: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'mediaService'
DEBUG: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'mediaService'
DEBUG: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'mediaService' to allow for resolving potential circular references
DEBUG: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'mediaService'
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Unable to locate LifecycleProcessor with name 'lifecycleProcessor': using default [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor@29d03e78]
DEBUG: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'lifecycleProcessor'
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Published root WebApplicationContext as ServletContext attribute with name [org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT]
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 393 ms
Mar 8, 2012 1:21:49 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Mar 8, 2012 1:21:49 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Mar 8, 2012 1:21:49 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/16  config=null
Mar 8, 2012 1:21:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 3687 ms
```

The problem bean is mediaDao. But it is created in the Spring container. And here is the Java source the issue is happening.

NoteService.java:

```
public class MediaService {

    @Autowired private MediaDao mediaDao;

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("NoteDao");

    /**
     * @param note
     * @return
     */
    public long addNote(Note note) {
        logger.info(" MediaService.addNote starts");
        long insertedId = -1;
        try  {
            insertedId = mediaDao.add(note);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.error(e);
        }

                logger.info(" MediaService.addNote ends");
        return insertedId;
    }
}
```

The mediaDao is null but other Java sources with @Autowired are OK. I don't know what is missing?

Answer (score 0):

You're not scanning the package of the class, so the annotation will be ignored. Add its package to a component scan element as you're already doing for the controller package.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have another question. <context:component-scan base-ackage="com.lodestone.ccah.controller"/> in the xxx-servlet.XML in use is not the configuration you're talking about?

Comment: @user1090973 No, that's not the package the service is in, nor is the service annotated with `@Service` (or other stereotype).

Answer (score 0):

My thought is, have you annotated the service with @Service annotation, if not then spring does not recognize that as spring managed class and it may not inject the DAO for you. Either it should Service or Component annotated. Also as told by Dave check the package whether the package is scanned by spring context or not. You have given the component scan for controller package. I am not sure whether the MediaService is also placed in the same package. Just check all these factors.

Answer (score 0):

The following is the correct form.

```
@Autowired private MediaDaoInterface mediaDaoInt;
```

Comment: Presumably you are suggesting that the OP creates an interface for the `mediaDao`, then injects the interface? Because Spring is proxying the class, so no instance of `MediaDao` can be found in the bean factory?

Comment: Yes, you need create the Interface and then when you inject the interface. too, You can´t create bean in beans.xml and using autowired both (sorry i speak english very bad :-P )